# How can I use String.format() to format doubles in Java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am trying to format double the same way as this but my Java is giving me an "IllegalFormatPrecisionException". How do I fix this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double t = 321.4532;
    String str = String.format("%.1d", t);
}
```

Comment: According to docs, the exception is thrown when the precision is a negative value other than -1, the conversion does not support a precision, or the value is otherwise unsupported.

Comment: Simply check the documentation for String.format() and you will see that `%d` is only supposed to be used with natural numbers and not reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%d is used for integer values try using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double t = 321.4532;
    String str = String.format("%.1f", t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from this [site][1]:

Don't try to use "d" for double here, because that is used to format integer and stands for decimal in formatting instruction.

Use %.2f and you will be good.

[1]: https://www.java67.com/2014/06/how-to-format-float-or-double-number-java-example.html#:~:text=format(%22%25.,float%20data%20type%20in%20Java.